# csv file is inserting a blank row in the last of other rows into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, csv

when i am inserting records from csv file to mysql table it also insert a blank row with other rows last of the other record.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
     $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
    if (!$connect) {
    die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
    }
   $cid =mysql_select_db('bizin490_devcredit',$connect);
      define('CSV_PATH', '/home/ubc/Documents/');
     $csv_file = CSV_PATH . "test.csv";
            $csvfile  = fopen($csv_file, 'r');
            $theData  = fgetcsv($csvfile);
            $i = 0;
            while (!feof($csvfile)) {
                $csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile, 1024);
                $csv_array  = explode(",", $csv_data[$i]);
                $insert_csv = array();
                $insert_csv['name']  = $csv_array[0];
                $insert_csv['email'] = $csv_array[1];
                $query = mysql_query("select name from test where name='" . $insert_csv['name'] . "'");
                $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
                if ($count == 0) {
                    $query = "INSERT INTO test(name,email)VALUES('" . $insert_csv['name'] . "','" . $insert_csv['email'] ."')";
                        $n = mysql_query($query, $connect);
                } else {
                    $sql = "update test set email='".$insert_csv['email']."'";
                            $qu  = mysql_query($sql);       
                }
     $i++;
                }

     fclose($csvfile);

            echo "File data successfully imported to database!!";
            mysql_close($connect);
            ?>
```

Comment: Don't use fgets(). If you can't use LOAD DATA INFILE, then at least use fgetcsv() and save yourself the arbitrariness of explode and worrying about quoted strings

Comment: And check whether `$csv_array[0]` is empty, only doing your select/insert/update if it isn't empty

Comment: Using [SPLFileObject](http://php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.fgetcsv.php) is even better, because you can tell it to ignore blank lines automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not very efficient one but add a condition

```
if ($insert_csv['name'] !== '' && $insert_csv['email']!=='') //since != '' will return true if you pass is numeric 0 and a few other cases, hence using !==
{
      $query = mysql_query("select name from test where name='" . $insert_csv['name'] . "'");
      $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
     if ($count == 0) {
                $query = "INSERT INTO test(name,email)VALUES('" . $insert_csv['name'] . "','" .  $insert_csv['email'] ."')";
                $n = mysql_query($query, $connect);
     } else {
                $sql = "update test set email='".$insert_csv['email']."'";
                $qu  = mysql_query($sql);       
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SplFileObject, and you can tell it to ignore empty lines, and to handle the file as a CSV file automatically

```
$file = new SplFileObject($csv_file);
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV | SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY);
foreach ($file as $csv_array) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are possible flaws in this code:

```
        $csvfile  = fopen($csv_file, 'r');           // opens the file
        $theData  = fgetcsv($csvfile);               // reads first line
        $i = 0;
        while (!feof($csvfile)) {                    // checks for eof
            $csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile, 1024);     // reads next line
```

1. When there's no header, the first row is skipped.
2. `feof` is `false` after the last line has been read. `fgets` doesn't check, whether there is data behind the last `\n`, so `feof` is false. `fgets` then reads the "empty" line until `eof` which is added falsely.

Change:

```
  // checks for eof and errors
  while ( ($csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile, 1024)) !== false) {  
       ...
  }
```